# Why is $C(\beta \mathbb{R})/C_0(\mathbb{R})\cong C(\beta \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{R})$ as $C^*$-algebras?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $\beta \mathbb{R}$ be the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ (with euclidean topology) and $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ the $C^*$-algebra of continuous complex-valued functions vanishing at infinity. Why is $C(\beta \mathbb{R})/C_0(\mathbb{R})\cong C(\beta \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{R})$ as $C^*$-algebras?

My problem is that I'm stuck to understand the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ and I dont know how to understand $\beta \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{R}$. 
I know that one can identify $C(\beta \mathbb{R})$ with $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ as $C^*$-algebras, the continuous bounded complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In general, if $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, and $U \subset X$ is open, then $C(X)/C_0(U) \cong C(X\setminus U)$ - just check that the restriction map from $C(X) \to C(X\setminus U)$ is surjective and has the right kernel.

Comment: thank you. I will write down a proof in my notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$C_0(\mathbb R)=\{f\in C(\beta\mathbb R):\ f|_{\beta\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb R}=0\}.$$

Comment: Thanks. With this identification it becomes clear

Comment: Glad I could help.